# How to fill a Direct3D texture with random RGB values. For use in a HLSL pixel shader

Tags: graphics, shader, textures, direct3d, hlsl

I am trying get 3 new random floats into my pixel shader for each pixel. Based on what I have read  [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/389617-how-to-generate-a-random-int-in-hlsl-pixel-shader/), [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32681/random-number-hlsl), and also  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149544/can-i-generate-a-random-number-inside-a-pixel-shader), I believe that I need to generate a large texture containing random RGB values and then during each draw call randomly generate a couple of texture coordinate offset values to produce a pseudo-random effect. Is the only way to do this through the LockRect and UnlockRect API? I hope not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They only way I have found to do this is the lock and unlock rectangle method. But it is much easier then I initially thought. Here is how I filled the texture. 
        'Create Random texture for dithering shader
        rando = New Random()
        randomText = New Texture(device, 1000, 1000, 1, Usage.Dynamic,
    Format.A16B16G16R16, Pool.Default)
        '89599
        '89510
        Dim data(1000 * 1000 * 8 + 1000 * 63 + 936) As Byte
        rando.NextBytes(data)

```
    Dim dataBox As DataRectangle =
randomText.GetSurfaceLevel(0).LockRectangle(LockFlags.None)
    dataBox.Data.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
    dataBox.Data.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    dataBox.Data.Close()
```

As you can see from the code I had to add a lot of extra bytes to completely fill the texture with random values. I used a 1000 x 1000 64bit texture so you would think I would need  1000*1000*8 Bytes of data but I need an extra 63936 Bytes to fill the texture and I am not sure why. But it seems to work for my needs.