# My own z-buffer

Tags: opengl, glsl, framebuffer, fbo, zbuffer

How I can make my own z-buffer for correct blending alpha channels? I'm using glsl.
I have only one idea. And this is use 2 "buffers", one of them storing depth-component and another color (with alpha channel). I don't need access to buffer in my program. I cant use uniform array because glsl have a restriction for the number of uniforms variables. I cant use FBO because behaviour for sometime writing and reading Frame Buffer is not defined (and dont working at any cards).

How I can resolve this problem?!

Or how to read actual real time z-buffer from glsl? (I mean for each fragment shader call z-buffer must be updated)

Comment: What does "correct blending alpha channels" mean? What problem are you trying to fix? Are you trying to do some order-independent thing?

Comment: In addition of what Nicol Bolas said: For Order Independent Transparency some additional depth buffer is not sufficient. What works splitting the scene in layers, which is called depth peeling. But the implementation of this is not trivial.

Comment: @NicolBolas, yes. If I can to read Z-Buffer from glsl then I have an easy way to do that!

Answer (score 3):

> How I can make my own z-buffer for correct blending alpha channels?

That's not possible. For perfect order-independent transparency you must get rid of z-buffer and replace it with another mechanism for hidden surface removal.

With z-buffer there are two possible ways to tackle the problem.

1. Multi-layered z-buffer (impractical with hardware acceleration) - basically it'll store several layers of "depth" values and will use it for blending transparent surfaces. Will hog a lot of memory, and there will be maximum number of transparent overlayying surfaces, once you're over the limit, there will be artifacts.
2. Depth peeling (google it). Order independent transparency, but there's a limit for maximum number of "overlaying" transparent polygons per pixel. Can actually be implemented on hardware.

Both approaches will have a limit (maximum number of overlapping transparent polygons per pixel), once you go over the limit, scene will no longer render properly. Which means the whole thing rather useless.

What you could actually do (to get perfect solution) is to remove the zbuffer completely, and make a graphic rendering pipeline that will gather all polygons to be rendered, clip them, split them (when two polygons intersect), sort them and then paint them on screen in correct order to ensure that you'll get correct result. However, this is hard, and doing it with hardware acceleration is harder. I think (I'm not completely certain it happened) 5 ot 6 years ago some ATI GPU-related document mentioned that some of their cards could render correct scene with Z-Buffer disabled by enabling some kind of extension. However, they didn't say a thing about alpha-blending. I haven't heard about this feature since. Perhaps it didn't become popular and shared the fate of TruForm (forgotten). Also such rendering pipeline will not be able to some things that are possible on z-buffer

Answer (score 2):

If it's order-independent transparencies you're after then the fundamental problem is that a depth buffer stores on depth per pixel but if you're composing a view of partially transparent geometry then more than one fragment contributes to each pixel.

If you were to solve the problem robustly you'd need an ordered list of depths per pixel, going back to the closest opaque fragment. You'd then walk the list in reverse order. In practice OpenGL doesn't do things like variably sized arrays so people achieve pretty much that by drawing their geometry in back-to-front order.

An alternative embodied by `GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE` is to switch to screen-door transparency, which is indistinguishable from real transparency either at a really high resolution or with multisampling. Ideally you'd do that stochastically, but that would void the OpenGL rule of repeatability. Nevertheless since you're in GLSL you can do it for yourself. Your sampler simply takes the input alpha and uses that as the probability that it'll output the final pixel. So grab a random value in the range 0.0 to 1.0 from somewhere and if it's greater than the alpha then discard the pixel. Always output with an alpha of 1.0 and just use the normal depth buffer. [Answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200224/random-noise-functions-for-glsl) say a bit more on what you can do to get randomish numbers in GLSL, and obviously you want to turn multisampling up as high as possible.

Eric Enderton has written [a decent paper](http://enderton.org/eric/pub/stochtransp-tvcg.pdf) (which has a [slide version](http://research.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/publications/StochTransp-slides.pdf)) on stochastic order-independent transparency that goes alongside a DirectX implementation that's worth checking out.