# How to replicate CIRandomGenerator using GPUImage framework

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, gpu, core-image

Anyone has an idea how to create a filter to generate random noise for the GPUImage framework?

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: I guess I can consider this a feature request. It's a little late here for me to pull something together, but you're really looking for a GLSL ES implementation of a noise function. Check out the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4200224/19679 , particularly Stefan Gustavson's, for various noise implementations that could be used. None of these look particularly fast, so some tuning might be required for these fragment shaders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's now a GPUImagePerlinNoiseFilter in the GPUImage framework based on the links in the thread referenced by Brad above.