# Noise Algorithm fails in Samsung Galaxy SIII (GLES)

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I am struggling to get the next simple algorithm working in the Samsung Galaxy SIII

```
float rand(vec2 co)
{
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

....
vec3 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
gl_FragColor.rgb = color + vec3(rand(gl_FragCoord.xy + time / 1000.0));
....
```

The code generates perfectly the expected noise in Samsung Galaxy S1 and Google Nexus S. But it fails completely in the new smartphone which uses ARM's Mali-400/MP4.

Anyone can spot anything wrong with this algorithm? Or maybe understand why could it fail?

Comment: Fails how? Are you checking the infologs for errors/warnings?

Comment: No errors at all, simply doesn't show any noise pixel. The overall image is ok, but without any noise.

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. I'd just recommend peeling it back one layer at a time until you can understand why. E.g. does fract() work? does fract(sin()) work, does fract(sin(dot((())) work? etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem likely comes from taking the `sin` of a big number. The result of this depends on the exact implementation of `sin`, which is not available. Obviously the `sin` function used by the Mali chip has more predictable results with big numbers than the others.

It seems to me that you should use [an *actual* noise function](https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise/wiki), not this thing. At least it will have predictable results across hardware.

Comment: I have tried this option as I though would be the best, and I've got very weird results. Cross hatching lines across everywhere instead of noise. I have used the next one from the library: https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise/blob/master/src/noise2D.glsl

Answer (score 5):

A bit of discussion of this issue on the ARM forums: http://forums.arm.com/index.php?/topic/16364-random-number-with-mali-400-mp/.

The problem is because of FP16 precision in fragment shaders on the Mali GPU.  Basically, there are no fractional bits left by the time `fract` is invoked (because the multipliers are so large), so you don't get any "noise" back at all.  If you make the constants smaller, you'll start getting non-zero values back, but they won't be noisy.  (I'm not entirely sure how the values were picked, and its [not clear where this algorithm came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964279/whats-the-origin-of-this-glsl-rand-one-liner)).

Technically this noise algorithm is relying on higher (medium? high?) precision floating point operations, which are optional in fragment shaders.  According to [this other post](http://forums.arm.com/index.php?/topic/15028-bug-in-driver-android-sgs-2-i9100/) you can check the platform's supported precision in fragment shaders by checking for  the "OES_fragment_precision_high" extension in `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`.

The [webgl-noise](https://github.com/ashima/webgl-noise/wiki) project in Nicol's answer doesn't seem as susceptible to floating-point truncation issues (it seems to keep things in a tighter bound).  However, it has a period of around 300, and it generates more "structured" noise than the "white" (or "pink") noise you currently get.  Its an excellent library, though, so its worth working into your code even if its not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: I ended up using the webgl-noise library, though I am still trying to find an alternative, as the algorithm is too big and besides sometimes (more than I wanted) produces noise which doesn't look quite as noise at all, specially when mixing with dark colors. So till now, besides the webgl-noise project, I haven't found any alternative.