# About noise in shaders

Tags: shader

[image]

When I use    `return fract(sin(dot(uv,vec2(18.13,98.16)))*19978.13);` to create random.
Why is there such a clear boundary?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `uv` (vec2) values are [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function), I would guess that this is caused by the `fract` function. What it does is `t-floor(t)`, but the [floor function is not continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). That in turn makes the `fract` a not continuous function too.

This kind of function seems to be discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964279/whats-the-origin-of-this-glsl-rand-one-liner).

The [Perlin noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) is a common source of pseudo randomness.