# Displaying Mesh in Vbo with different point sizes?

Tags: opengl, mesh, vbo, openframeworks, glpointsize

I'm trying to display a Mesh as points with a Vbo in openFrameworks.

I would like all the points to have different sizes, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily if you're using a vertex shader.  Specifically, you can set `gl_PointSize` to a unique value for each vertex in the vertex shader

```
void main()
{
    gl_PointSize = <value>;
    // ...
}
```

If you know what value you want per vertex, you can pass that in as an additional vertex attribute, or you could generate it from a function.  If you want to randomly set the point sizes, which could be useful or distracting depending on what you're doing, you could either try using the `noise` GLSL function, or check [this answer about generating random numbers in GLSL shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200224/random-noise-functions-for-glsl) if `noise` isn't supported in the GLSL you're using (e.g., if you're using WebGL).

Comment: This is a great answer, it saved a lot of time I would have otherwise spent exploring, so thank you. I just wanted to add to this answer that `glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE)` needs to called before the draw call and corresponding `glDisable()` after the draw call

Comment: @quantumshiv I'm glad you found it useful.  Thanks for the kind words.