# Pseudo-Random vec2 creation with GLSL

Tags: opengl, random, glsl

I want to access the color of the pixels in the Moore neighborhood of my cellular automaton. Therefore a frame buffer was created and the current screen image is passed as Sampler2D to the GLSL shader program (like in post processing etc...). To access the neighboring pixel color I add or subtract one to the texture coordinate. This looks basically like this:

```
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D texFrameBuffer;
void main( void )
{
   gl_FragColor = texture(texFrameBuffer, vec2(TexCoord.x+1, TexCoord.y-1));
};
```

[image: Moore Neighborhood]

Which of the 8 surrounding pixels will be accessed should be random. Is there a (not too much time consuming) random function that returns {1.0, -1.0}, so that a `vec2` can be added to `TexCoord` to access a random pixel?

Comment: The closest thing you are going to get to random in GLSL is [`noise`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/noise.xml), and it does satisfy your conditions. But you do not seed it like you would a traditional stateful prng... your input (texture coordinate in this case) would serve as the seed (every time you use it), and a subsequent execution of `noise` with the same input will give the same output.

Comment: Is there a appropriate solution for OpenGL ES?

Comment: AFAIK noise is not supported by most drivers.

Answer (score 2):

The usual hack for things like this is to use a hash function on your current texture coordinate, offset by either time (passed in as a uniform) or a random number generated on the CPU each frame (again passed in as a uniform).

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200224/random-noise-functions-for-glsl) for some simple hash functions in GLSL.