# Gaussian-distributed pseudo-random number generator in GLSL

Tags: opengl, random, glsl

I need to generate normally-distributed pseudo-random numbers in a GLSL version 120 fragment shader.

They don't even have to be particularly *good* pseudo-random numbers. But they do need to be normally distributed.

I think I know where to look if I want to write my own random number generator, but I wanted to see if such a thing had already been invented. I'd also be grateful for any links to uniformly distributed random number generators in GLSL 120.

As a note, I've already seen the [random noise generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200224/random-noise-functions-for-glsl) question for GLSL. Unfortunately, it looks like simplex and Perlin noise has some kind of multimodal distribution. I suppose I could just use the mod function, but I wondered if there was a more appropriate method.

Comment: If others are curious, there are some noise functions included in GLSL 120, such as `noise1` and `noise2`. I haven't had a chance to verify that they're normally distributed, though.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3956538/2521214