# How to solve Noise Screen Error in Android ? (like noise in tv)

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I just build APK using Unity `2017.4.34f1`, However, when going to a scene the view becomes noise like below:

[image: unity noise in a scene]

Note:

1) Main Scene is fine, the error is from next scene

2) My Device is using `Android 8.0.0` (Sony xperia so-01j)

3) This APK not directly generated by Unity, but first exported to Android Studio then build APK from there

**build.gradle:**

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       google() // here
       jcenter()
       maven {
           url "https://jitpack.io"
       }
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}





// Android Resolver Repos Start
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = "file:///" + file(rootProject.projectDir.path + "/../../").absolutePath
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:[26.0.0, 27.2.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0, 27.2.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0, 27.2.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 12.1.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:3
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[10.2.1, 12.1.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 12.1.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:4
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-drive-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-games-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-gcm-12.0.1', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-iid-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-nearby-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
//  implementation(name: 'com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'onesignal-unity', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'udp', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'udpsandbox', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'UnityChannel', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'utils', ext:'aar')
    implementation project(':common_lib')
    implementation project(':GoogleMobileAdsPlugin')
    implementation project(':OneSignalConfig')
    implementation project(':sdkbox_review_lib')
    implementation project(':youtube_lib')
}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

    task removeBuildConfig(dependsOn: "compileReleaseSources") {
        doFirst {
            file("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/release/pathToFile/BuildConfig.class").delete()
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 29
        applicationId 'com.mygameapps.study'
        minSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 281
        versionName "2.0.281"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
        }
        //abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
    }

    signingConfigs { release {
        storeFile file('mykey.keystore')
        storePassword 'xyz123'
        keyAlias 'mygame apps development team'
        keyPassword 'xyz123'
    } }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt','proguard-user.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt','proguard-user.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}
```

**Unity Player Setting:**

[image]

I attached adb log, although, i'm not sure can bee seen from here:

```
05-03 15:32:10.431 31498 31697 W GoogleTagManager: Event does not have parameter "promotions" and no default value was defined. Returning "undefined".
05-03 15:32:11.247  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: IrPSensor:setPSensorPower() : Power OFF
05-03 15:32:11.247  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: PSensorObserver:onPSensorStateChanged() : isNear = false
05-03 15:32:11.251  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: AccSensor(180133500):setPSensorPower() : Power OFF
05-03 15:32:11.259  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: TransmitPowerService:setPowerBackOffFactor() : key = 16, value = 0
05-03 15:32:11.261  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 1
05-03 15:32:11.263  3911  3911 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]invokeOemRilRequestRaw: serial=1195 length=24
05-03 15:32:11.267  3911  3935 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookResponse serial no: 1195 error: 0length=0
05-03 15:32:11.268  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 2
05-03 15:32:11.269  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: sendOemRilRequestRaw returns value = 0
05-03 15:32:12.166  3911  3935 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookIndication length=21
05-03 15:32:12.167  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 0
05-03 15:32:12.177  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:12.177  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:12.177  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:12.177  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:12.177  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:12.177  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:12.177  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:12.177  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:12.294   677   677 W memtrack@1.0-se: type=1400 audit(0.0:5659): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=8110 scontext=u:r:hal_memtrack_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
05-03 15:32:13.265  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: IrPSensor:setPSensorPower() : Power ON
05-03 15:32:13.268  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: AccSensor(180133500):setPSensorPower() : Power ON
05-03 15:32:13.268  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: PSensorObserver:onPSensorStateChanged() : isNear = false
05-03 15:32:13.282  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: AccSensorObserver:onMotionStateChanged() : isStable = false
05-03 15:32:13.287  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: TransmitPowerService:setPowerBackOffFactor() : key = 16, value = 16
05-03 15:32:13.288  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 1
05-03 15:32:13.289  3911  3911 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]invokeOemRilRequestRaw: serial=1196 length=24
05-03 15:32:13.291  3911  3935 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookResponse serial no: 1196 error: 0length=0
05-03 15:32:13.291  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 2
05-03 15:32:13.292  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: sendOemRilRequestRaw returns value = 0
05-03 15:32:13.885  3911  3935 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookIndication length=21
05-03 15:32:13.885  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 0
05-03 15:32:13.896  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:13.896  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:13.896  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:13.897  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:13.897  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:13.897  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:13.898  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:13.898  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:14.276  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: IrPSensor:setPSensorPower() : Power OFF
05-03 15:32:14.276  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: PSensorObserver:onPSensorStateChanged() : isNear = false
05-03 15:32:14.282  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: AccSensor(180133500):setPSensorPower() : Power OFF
05-03 15:32:14.286  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: TransmitPowerService:setPowerBackOffFactor() : key = 16, value = 0
05-03 15:32:14.287  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 1
05-03 15:32:14.291  3911  3911 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]invokeOemRilRequestRaw: serial=1197 length=24
05-03 15:32:14.294  3911  3935 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookResponse serial no: 1197 error: 0length=0
05-03 15:32:14.295  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 2
05-03 15:32:14.296  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: sendOemRilRequestRaw returns value = 0
05-03 15:32:15.414   677   677 W memtrack@1.0-se: type=1400 audit(0.0:5661): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=8110 scontext=u:r:hal_memtrack_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
05-03 15:32:15.431  4013  4013 W ChimeraUtils: Non Chimera context
05-03 15:32:15.432  4013  4013 W ChimeraUtils: Non Chimera context
05-03 15:32:15.494   677   677 W memtrack@1.0-se: type=1400 audit(0.0:5663): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=8110 scontext=u:r:hal_memtrack_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
05-03 15:32:15.524   677   677 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) memtrack@1.0-se identical 2 lines
05-03 15:32:15.524   677   677 W memtrack@1.0-se: type=1400 audit(0.0:5666): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=8110 scontext=u:r:hal_memtrack_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
05-03 15:32:15.649 31380 31429 D Unity   : Unloading 4 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
05-03 15:32:15.695 31380 31395 D Unity   : UnloadTime: 18.417000 ms
05-03 15:32:15.717 31380 31395 D Unity   : System memory in use before: 34.9 MB.
05-03 15:32:15.743 31380 31395 D Unity   : System memory in use after: 35.0 MB.
05-03 15:32:15.743 31380 31395 D Unity   : 
05-03 15:32:15.743 31380 31395 D Unity   : Unloading 3 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 2516.
05-03 15:32:15.743 31380 31395 D Unity   : Total: 26.378000 ms (FindLiveObjects: 1.101000 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.714000 ms MarkObjects: 24.468000 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.087000 ms)
05-03 15:32:15.743 31380 31395 D Unity   : 
05-03 15:32:18.911  3911  3935 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookIndication length=21
05-03 15:32:18.911  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 0
05-03 15:32:18.917  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:18.918  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:18.943  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:18.943  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:18.943  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:18.943  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:18.944  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:18.944  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:19.670  3911  3935 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookIndication length=21
05-03 15:32:19.671  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 0
05-03 15:32:19.683  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:19.683  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:19.710  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:19.711  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:19.711  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:19.711  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:19.711  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:19.711  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:19.874   677   677 W memtrack@1.0-se: type=1400 audit(0.0:5667): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=8110 scontext=u:r:hal_memtrack_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
05-03 15:32:19.994   677   677 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) memtrack@1.0-se identical 4 lines
05-03 15:32:19.994   677   677 W memtrack@1.0-se: type=1400 audit(0.0:5672): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=8110 scontext=u:r:hal_memtrack_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
05-03 15:32:24.687  3911  3935 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookIndication length=21
05-03 15:32:24.687  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 0
05-03 15:32:24.695  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:24.695  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:24.703  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:24.704  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:24.704  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:24.704  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:24.704  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:24.704  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:26.602  3911  3935 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookIndication length=21
05-03 15:32:26.602  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 0
05-03 15:32:26.606  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:26.606  3821  3821 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:26.619  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:26.620  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:26.622  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:26.623  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:26.623  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Received Broadcast Intent ACTION_UNSOL_RESPONSE_OEM_HOOK_RAW
05-03 15:32:26.623  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: Oem ID in QCRILHOOK UNSOL RESP is QOEMHOOK
05-03 15:32:30.545  2733  3930 I ActivityManager: Killing 30500:com.android.providers.calendar/u0a52 (adj 904): empty #17
05-03 15:32:30.554   677   677 W memtrack@1.0-se: type=1400 audit(0.0:5673): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=8110 scontext=u:r:hal_memtrack_default:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 ppid=1 pcomm="init" pgid=1 pgcomm="init"
05-03 15:32:30.554  2733  3930 I ActivityManager: Killing 29727:com.joelapenna.foursquared/u0a400 (adj 906): empty #18
05-03 15:32:30.618  2733  3431 D ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=103, [ Capabilities: NOT_METERED&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&FOREGROUND] ], android.os.BinderProxy@f4c3787)
05-03 15:32:30.619  2733  3408 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=103, [ Capabilities: NOT_METERED&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&FOREGROUND] ]
05-03 15:32:31.226 31498 31616 D CMUserHandler: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
05-03 15:32:31.399  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: IrPSensor:setPSensorPower() : Power ON
05-03 15:32:31.405  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: AccSensor(180133500):setPSensorPower() : Power ON
05-03 15:32:31.405  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: PSensorObserver:onPSensorStateChanged() : isNear = false
05-03 15:32:31.408  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: AccSensorObserver:onMotionStateChanged() : isStable = false
05-03 15:32:31.411  3840  3840 D TransmitPower: TransmitPowerService:setPowerBackOffFactor() : key = 16, value = 16
05-03 15:32:31.411  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 1
05-03 15:32:31.415  3911  3911 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]invokeOemRilRequestRaw: serial=1198 length=24
05-03 15:32:31.418  3911  3935 I QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookResponse serial no: 1198 error: 0length=0
05-03 15:32:31.419  3911  3911 D QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 2
05-03 15:32:31.420  3840  3840 D QC_RIL_OEM_HOOK: sendOemRilRequestRaw returns value = 0
```

Any Idea?

Comment: no idea, post screenshots of player and quality settings from the build, also what android version is your phone running?

Comment: Hi @vasmos, I have update my question