# Calling a javascript function from a fragment shader (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I am pretty new to webgl, and I've tried finding answers to my problem in old questions but I haven't been able to find any.

My problem is that I in my fragment shader need a function that generates a random number between -1 and 1. As I understand it I need to make a function myself, because HTML doesn't have a random number generator but Javascript does. I made this function in the head:

```
<script = "text/javascript">
function random() {
return Math.random()*2-1;    //random number between -1 and 1
}
</script>
```

When I then try to call the function in the fragment shader, I am told that no overloaded function is found. But I can't really figure out how I am suppose to declare and call the function then. This is how I try to invoke it in the fragment shader:

```
 ...
 for (float i = 0.0 ; i < no_of_samples ; i ++){

        ndc.x = 2.0*((gl_FragCoord.x+half_pixelsize*random())/width-0.5);  

 ...
```

Comment: Be aware `Math.random()*2-1` should include -1 but not +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Calling functions like that is impossible.**

GLSL is compiled by a completely different compiler (probably provided by the GPU driver) and it's completely unaware of the JavaScript environment.

You may want to look at GLSL solutions, e.g.: [Random / noise functions for GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200224/random-noise-functions-for-glsl).

Comment: It's possible to write a compiler that [translates JavaScript functions into GLSL](https://github.com/stackgl/glsl-transpiler), so it should be possible to call those functions from a shader.