# Generating a Pseudo-random number between 0 an 1 GLSL ES

Tags: random, glsl, glsles

I am trying to create a pseudo random float between 0.0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (inclusive) in GLSL ES in order to process the mutations for a chromosome on the GPU rather than a CPU in a genetic algorithm. How would I go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random / noise functions for GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200224/random-noise-functions-for-glsl)

Comment: Check this one out: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4djSRW

Answer (score 1):

```
float random(vec2 st)
{
    return fract(sin(dot(st.xy, vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453123);
}
```

If you want to learn more about this function, here's a link from The Book of Shaders: https://thebookofshaders.com/10/