# 2D perlin noise appears to be boxy

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, procedural-programming

I seem to be getting boxy perlin noise terrain on 2d input.

I have been following this https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4tGSzW, which uses WebGL instead of opengl. Where i have replaced the gradient method of taking from some sample texture by a float array of range 0.0 to 1.0.

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;


uniform float gradient[256];

float fade(float t)
{
    return t*t*t*(t*(t*6.0-15.0)+10.0);
}


vec2 grad(vec2 p){
    vec2 v = vec2(gradient[int(p.x)&255],gradient[int(p.y)&255]);
    return normalize(v.xy*2.0 - vec2(1.0));
}

float noise(vec2 p){
    vec2 p0 = floor(p);
    vec2 p1 = p0 + vec2(1.0,0.0);
    vec2 p2 = p0 + vec2(0.0,1.0);
    vec2 p3 = p0 + vec2(1.0,1.0);

    vec2 g0 = grad(p0);
    vec2 g1 = grad(p1);
    vec2 g2 = grad(p2);
    vec2 g3 = grad(p3);

    float t0 = p.x - p0.x;
    float fade_t0 = fade(t0);
    float t1 = p.y - p0.y;
    float fade_t1 = fade(t1);

    float p0p1 = (1.0-fade_t0)*dot(g0,(p-p0)) + fade_t0*dot(g1,(p-p1));
    float p2p3 = (1.0-fade_t0)*dot(g2,(p-p2)) + fade_t0*dot(g3,(p-p3));

    return ((1.0-fade_t1)*p0p1 + fade_t1*p2p3);
}


void main()
{
    float n = noise(vec2(gl_FragCoord.x,gl_FragCoord.y)/64.0)*1.0 +
              noise(vec2(gl_FragCoord.x,gl_FragCoord.y)/32.0) * 0.5 +
              noise(vec2(gl_FragCoord.x,gl_FragCoord.y)/16.0) * 0.25 +
              noise(vec2(gl_FragCoord.x,gl_FragCoord.y)/8.0) * 0.125;


    FragColor = vec4(vec3(n*0.5+0.5),1.0);

}
```

[Boxy perlin noise Image being generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IGd0.png)

Comment: Can you post a picture of how your noise looks?

Comment: @ Kalle Halvarsson done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source texture in the shadertoy version is 2 dimensional and consists of 256*256 random pixels and multiple color channels. 
Further when the texture is looked up in the original `grad` function then the pixels are interpolated according to the texture minification filter, which is probably `GL_LINEAR`.

> ```c
> vec2 grad(vec2 p) {
>   const float texture_width = 256.0;
>   vec4 v = texture(iChannel0, vec2(p.x / texture_width, p.y / texture_width));
>    return normalize(v.xy*2.0 - vec2(1.0));
> }
> ```

Your uniform array has just 256 different values and the interpolation between the texels is not emulated in your `grad` function:

> ```c
> vec2 grad(vec2 p){
>    vec2 v = vec2(gradient[int(p.x)&255],gradient[int(p.y)&255]);
>    return normalize(v.xy*2.0 - vec2(1.0));
> }
> ```

Use a [Random noise functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200224/random-noise-functions-for-glsl) and interpret the return value of the noise function as an angle (noise*2*PI) to calculate the return value of `grad()`:

```c
float rand(vec2 co){
    return fract(sin(dot(co.xy, vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}

vec2 grad(vec2 p){
    float a = rand(p) * 2.0 * 3.1415926;
    return vec2(cos(a), sin(a)); 
}
```

[image]

Or use the uniform array to generate a random value

```c
vec2 grad(vec2 p){

    ivec2 i00 = ivec2(int(p.x)&255, int(p.y)&255); 
    vec2  f   = floor(p); 

    float vx = mix(gradient[i00.x], gradient[i00.x+1], f.x);
    float vy = mix(gradient[i00.y], gradient[i00.y+1], f.y);

    float a = (vx + vy) * 3.141529;
    return vec2(cos(a), sin(a)); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the solution, I am getting the desired results. But here i think it's not interpolation whats causing the boxy noise as i am always passing a floor(vec2) to grad as input. Are the values being generated by me not random enough or something else?

Comment: @ashish As I mentioned in the first sentence of the answer  *"The source texture in the shadertoy version is 2 dimensional and consists of 256*256 random pixels ans multiple color channels. [...] Your uniform array has just 256 different values"*

Comment: so theoretically if have a uniform array of 256*256 random pixel values(for each of the two components of vec2), it should work with the old approach?

Comment: @ashish Of course. But note 256*256 floats exceeds the limit of the (default) uniform block size. The proper solution for this is to use a texture (or a random noise function).

Comment: okay, now i get it. Me picking values for x and y component from 256 floats was making the so called random values not random as either x was repeating horizontally or y was repeating vertically hence the boxy appearance. Thanks.