# mixing of noise from four corner glsl

Tags: random, graphics, glsl, shader, perlin-noise

I am studying noise from the [bookofshaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/11/)  and in 2d noise this is the code in the book or website.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

// 2D Random
float random (in vec2 st) {
    return fract(sin(dot(st.xy,
                         vec2(12.9898,78.233)))
                 * 43758.5453123);
}

// 2D Noise based on Morgan McGuire @morgan3d
// https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dS3Wd
float noise (in vec2 st) {
    vec2 i = floor(st);
    vec2 f = fract(st);

    // Four corners in 2D of a tile
    float a = random(i);
    float b = random(i + vec2(1.0, 0.0));
    float c = random(i + vec2(0.0, 1.0));
    float d = random(i + vec2(1.0, 1.0));

    // Smooth Interpolation

    // Cubic Hermine Curve.  Same as SmoothStep()
    vec2 u = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    // u = smoothstep(0.,1.,f);

    // Mix 4 coorners percentages
    return mix(a, b, u.x) +
            (c - a)* u.y * (1.0 - u.x) +
            (d - b) * u.x * u.y;
}

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;

    // Scale the coordinate system to see
    // some noise in action
    vec2 pos = vec2(st*5.0);

    // Use the noise function
    float n = noise(pos);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(n), 1.0);
}
```

There are few things i am not able to understand in this code is

1. why is the mixing or combining noise value from all the corner has calculation like that

   ```
     mix(a, b, u.x) + (c - a)* u.y * (1.0 - u.x) + (d - b) * u.x * u.y;
   ```

from initial understanding it is easy guess that everything is linear interpolation but i am not able to understand the thinking behind why `u.y*(1.0-u.x)` and `u.x*u.y` are used as a factor.

is it something like someone choosed this specific way and there is no concerete reason why it is specificially done this way or this mixing is not standard way of mixing but people can mix anyway they want ?

2. and in the line of code

   ```
    vec2 pos = vec2(st*5.0)
   ```

i am not able to understand how does this increase the frequency of noise.

can anyone please help me understand this ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200224/random-noise-functions-for-glsl

Comment: 1) looks like a simplified bilinear interpolation (or at least a modified version of it) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

Comment: @PeterO. thank you for comment, i checked that before posting but could not find answer from that. My main question is what was the thinking behind that math of mixing.

Comment: @yosmo78 yes thank you so much for pointing me to right direction, yes it turned out rearranged bilinear interpolation. Thank you so much

Comment: @PravinPoudel as for 2), st desribes every pixel in Space in the Space of [(0,0)-(width,height)] as a fraction in the space [(0,0)-(1,1)]. So since you can think that your noise function is f(x) where x is the fraction in the space between 0 to 1 for each component of the vector. You are then sampling that function at each pixel on the screen. then you are just scaling the input to the noise function (in essence shrinking the input space)

Answer (score 0):

for question 1,

that equation was just complicated version of

```
float a1 = mix(a, b, u.x);
float b1 = mix(c, d, u.x);
return mix(a1, b1, u.y);
```

Thank you